# Drupal WSOD error caused by 'drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);' in index.php

Tags: php, drupal

So I'm required to fix this issue with a drupal website while having no experience at all with drupal.
The issue is the website is not loading up, just a white screen, no errors are coming up even after adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

By putting in some die()s I was able to find out the line that's causing the issue which is `drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);`

Here's the full sourcecode for index.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
// $Id: index.php,v 1.94 2007/12/26 08:46:48 dries Exp $

/**
 * @file
 * The PHP page that serves all page requests on a Drupal installation.
 *
 * The routines here dispatch control to the appropriate handler, which then
 * prints the appropriate page.
 *
 * All Drupal code is released under the GNU General Public License.
 * See COPYRIGHT.txt and LICENSE.txt.
 */
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
// reaching here
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
// does not reach here

$return = menu_execute_active_handler();

// Menu status constants are integers; page content is a string.
if (is_int($return)) {
  switch ($return) {
    case MENU_NOT_FOUND:
      drupal_not_found();
      break;
    case MENU_ACCESS_DENIED:
      drupal_access_denied();
      break;
    case MENU_SITE_OFFLINE:
      drupal_site_offline();
      break;
  }
}
elseif (isset($return)) {
  // Print any value (including an empty string) except NULL or undefined:
  print theme('page', $return);
}


drupal_page_footer();
```

Tried a lot of the suggestions online but nothing fixed it and I'm not receiving any hints just this white screen.

I suspected the issue might be related to the `.htaccess` file but I don't think it is, here's its source code:

```
########GET#######
########GET#######
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|svn-base)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Force simple error message for requests for non-existent favicon.ico.
<Files favicon.ico>
  # There is no end quote below, for compatibility with Apache 1.3.
  ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.
</Files>

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Override PHP settings. More in sites/default/settings.php
# but the following cannot be changed at runtime.

# PHP 4, Apache 1.
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 4, Apache 2.
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  # Do not cache dynamically generated pages.
  ExpiresByType text/html A1
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # adapt and uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment and adapt the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# $Id: .htaccess,v 1.90.2.3 2008/12/10 20:04:08 goba Exp $
```

As requested here's the error log from the cpanel:

```
2015-08-26 14:15:42.042 [INFO] [23.239.196.71:3490] File not found [/home/omitted/public_html/index.php] 
2015-08-26 14:15:42.042 [INFO] [23.239.196.71:3490] File not found [/home/omitted/public_html/index.php] 
2015-08-26 14:15:41.581 [INFO] [23.239.196.71:3478] File not found [/home/omitted/public_html/403.shtml] 
2015-08-26 14:15:41.580 [INFO] [23.239.196.71:3478] Auto Index is disabled for [/home/omitted/public_html/], access denied
2015-08-26 13:55:33.364 [INFO] [157.55.39.230:2610] File not found [/home/omitted/public_html/index.php] 
2015-08-26 13:55:33.364 [INFO] [157.55.39.230:2610] File not found [/home/omitted/public_html/index.php] 
2015-08-26 12:49:51.204 [INFO] [158.69.2.151:51437] File not found [/home/omitted/public_html/403.shtml] 
2015-08-26 12:49:51.204 [INFO] [158.69.2.151:51437] Auto Index is disabled for [/home/omitted/public_html/], access denied
```

Comment: Both of these files look pretty standard. Are there any errors listed in your webserver logs?

Comment: @aaronott thanks for the comment. it doesn't look like it has anything out of the ordinary or related to my issue. I added it to the question.

Comment: It looks like these are related to your issue. The configuration is unable to find your index.php file or the directory does not have the proper permissions to read either your home directory, or the public_html directory. Would you mind doing `ls -ld /home/omitted` and `ls -ld /home/omitted/public_html` This will help troubleshoot permissions.

Comment: @aaronott Sorry I should have mentioned that the drupal website is in /provent, the public_html is not accessed at all and that's why there's no index.php there

Comment: If drupal site was placed in subfolder you should read this answer to adjust your settings: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73782/how-to-get-drupal-7-installed-in-a-sub-folder-sub-directory-properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced this on a site that had been active for over a yer. How frustrating! I changed the Drupal settings to point to another database server, and it worked fine. 
Answer for me that it was the mysql database server (which I do not control and little visibility) had full logs, but was not throwing an appropriate error. Once the server admin fixed the issue, it worked fine.